# How to search word with special characters in Kibana - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, kibana-7

Does anyone know how I could get the values containing that value in message? If I remove the (-) and (/) it searches, if I leave them, the query does not return anything.

Not....

```
GET my-index/_search
{
   "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "message": "*Z-01-123456-9/2020-1*"
        }
    }
}
```

Not....

```
GET my-index/_search
{
   "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "message": "*Z\\-01\\-123456\\-9\/2020\-1*"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {"message": "Z-01-123456-9/2020-1"}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-06-16T07:00:00",
              "lt": "2020-06-23T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
    "message": "Z-01-123456-9/2020-1"
}
{
  "message": "K-01-123456-9/2020-12"
}
{
  "message": "Z-01-123456-9/2020-12"
}
```

**Search Query:**

**The prerequisite is to have field not analyzed. Values of type "keyword" are not analyzed and are indexed as it is.**

```
{
   "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "message": "*Z-01-123456-9/2020-1*"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test2",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Z-01-123456-9/2020-1"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test2",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "message": "Z-01-123456-9/2020-12"
                }
            }
        ]
```

You can even Ignore special characters in query with pattern replace filter and custom analyzer.

Comment: @Max  did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)